# JAVA Server receiving whitespace

Tags: java, server, whitespace

I'm trying to receive data from a client (the data sent with unknown format).
the data that I'm receiving has a lot of white spaces for example:
the client send the number 1.50 I get in the server 1 . 5 0,
how can I convert it to normal double back?

```
int port = 1245;
     ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    try {
    while(true)
    {
    //Reading the message from the client
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String number = br.readLine();

            console.getOut().println(number);

            //Multiplying the number by 2 and forming the return message
            String returnMessage;

    }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
     console.getOut().println("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
  }
   }
     catch(Exception e) {
     console.getOut().println("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
  }
```

Comment: Add your client code

Comment: This is more than some whitespace, this looks like a value used after each character. I have seen that with a bluetooth scanner that could use that as a splitter of character

Comment: Is the line guaranteed to only ever contain a single number?

Comment: Seems to be a character encoding issue. In particular, if the client sends UTF-16 and you expect UTF-8 you would get 0 bytes between characters. Make sure the same encoding is used on client and server.

Comment: I agree with @Henry. It would be easy to write a regexp to remove the whitespace, null characters or whatever they are; but you will want to understand why they appear and learn whether more surprises in data are in for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the client is in MQL code (which close to C++ I think), it use the win_32 dll library to send strings...any idea what should I change in the client?
thanks